# What is the proper beracha on granola bars

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, orach-chaim, mezonot-beracha

According to Halacha what is the proper beracha to be made on granola bars? Is it mezonot  or maybe something else? Is this question  a machloket amongst the  poskim?

Comment: What are they made of and how are they processed?

Comment: This is one of those ask your local Orthodox Rabbi questions. You'll get different answers depending on who you ask.

Comment: If the individual oats are visible, some may recommend shehakol.

Comment: @NT If you ask my rabbi, he'll tell you to only eat them during a bread meal. YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the epitome of a safek brachos. Whenever a maggid shiur wants to give an example of a modern day food that is a real debate on the bracha, they use granola and granola bars (two very distinct issues). As far as granola bars goes, besides the ingredients, the process is also a key factor.

From the [OU](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/what-beracha-does-one-recite-on-a-granola-bar/#:%7E:text=Never%20the%20less%2C%20Rabbi%20Belsky,other%20ingredients%20are%20considered%20tofel.):

> If one does not understand the process involved in creating a granola bar, one could study the ingredient panel a hundred times and still not be able to answer the above question. However, through our access to the companies that produce these bars we are privy to information that is important in resolving this issue

> In the late nineteenth century “Granola” was a trademark for foods consisting of whole grains that were crumbled and baked until crispy. Today, granola bars are made from whole grain oats that are first cooked until softened and then rolled into flat flakes. They are then combined with sugars, oils and syrups and baked. The Mishna Berura (Orach Chaim 208:3) states that if grains are reduced and broken down in the cooking process, even if they were introduced whole, one should recite Mezonos. The granola bar grains appear to remain whole. The Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 208:4) says that on whole toasted grains the proper Beracha is Borei Pri Hoadoma. In many granola bars the oats actually comprise less than fifty percent of the volume of the bar. The majority of the ingredients are those on which one would recite a Shehakol. Never the less, Rabbi Belsky and Rabbi Schachter have said that the proper Beracha Rishona to be recited when eating a granola bar is Borei Pri Haodoma. The oats (granola) are clearly considered the ikar, and all the other ingredients are considered tofel. We should therefore follow the regular rules of ikar vitofel and recite Hoadoma. Some poskim, however, consider the cooking process together with the subsequent baking to be a maiseh kideira. They posit that through all the cooking and baking, the grains must be partially broken down, and the proper beracha to be recited, as per the above mentioned Mishna Berura, would be Mezonos. Whether one recites Haodoma or Mezonos either way one would be yotzai bidieved. The disagreement is as to which beracha should be recited lichatchila.

Comment: "Whether one recites Haodoma or Mezonos either way one would be yotzai bidieved. The disagreement is as to which beracha should be recited lichatchila." But for bracha acharona it matters a lot more.

Comment: Yes. But the op asked about the bracha rishona.